# Reason for capacitor on ATX 12V+ wire

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, atx

I'm using a computer PSU to power several controller boards and sensors. 
To be more precise, I'm using the 24pin ATX connector wires to power everything.

There are two 12V+ wires coming from the connector. I've noticed that one of these wires is connected to a ground wire via a capacitor. While the other wire is just a stand alone 12V+. I assume the capacitor is to smoothen the power supply on that wire?

Can anyone explain the reason for the capacitor?

Comment: Who put the capacitor there?

Comment: Corsair, the manufacturer of the PSU.

Comment: Capacitors between +12 V and GND in an ATX power supply are intended for supply filtering. Although you didn't find any yet, the other 12 V line will also have such smoothing capacitors. That capacitor you found is probably there since there was no other place to put it.

Comment: Thank you Bimpelrekkie.

Comment: It is not clear from the description where the capacitor is. Outside the PSU? Inside? But in either case, if it is old PSU it most likely has single 12V rail, which means all yellow wires are connected together anyway, so the capacitor location does not matter much

Comment: There's a couple of connectors plugged into the PSU. The wires form these connectors merge into a single 24pin ATX connector. The wire that goes to pin 10 of the ATX connector has a capicitor on it. But the question has already been answered.